# Recover Vsphere VMs by folder with postman request?

Tags: request, postman, vsphere, vcenter

I try to recover each VM by folder by using request from postman.

With this request, I'm able to list each folder in my vsphere :

```
GET https://SERVER/rest/vcenter/folder
```

With this second command, I'm able to list each VM in my vpshere :

```
GET https://SERVER/rest/vcenter/vm
```

I want to know if there is a way to get a folder and each VMS inside it ?

Something like :

```
GET https://SERVER/rest/vcenter/folder/my_folder
```

With an output like :

```
"value": [
        {
            "folder": "XXX",
               "VMs" : {
                VM1
                VM2
                ...
```

Or someting like that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

http://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest/6.5/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/folder.list-operation.html

```
&filter.parent_folders.1=obj-103
```

it supports query parameter parent_folders , so the url will be like

```
GET https://SERVER/rest/vcenter/folder?filters.filter.parent_folders.1=obj-103
```

Even VM supports the filter called folder:

http://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest/6.5/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm.list-operation.html